# Chrome cannot download any file on a FTP server

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ftp

If I click on a link that redirect to an ftp server (eg: ftp://files.scene.org/somefile.zip), nothing happen (file is not downloaded as it should be).
If I open Chrome *Network* tab (by clicking on the page and choosing *Inspect*) here is what I got :
[image]

[image]

In *Preview* and *Response* tabs, it says *Failed to load response data*.

What I tried :

- If I open a new tab, paste an ftp link and press enter, nothing happen (other than reporting an error in *Network* tab).
- If I right click on a ftp link and choose *Save As*, it works (file is downloaded).
- If I try the same links on another computer in Chrome (same version) it works.

EDIT:
I have been able to make it work by explicitly enabling FTP support in Chrome:
[image]

It was set on *Default*.
I checked on the other computer (where FTP links works) and it's set on *Default* as well. I am not sure what *Default* means but it seems it behave differently depending computer.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else comes across this. I had a user come to me asking for help downloading a file using a FTP link in Chrome. Turns out that Chrome removed FTP support recently. You can re-enable it like they did above if you have version 88 or earlier. Version 89 slated for Q1 of 2021 is expected to remove all FTP code so you will no longer be able to re-enable it with flags. You'll have to use a different browser like Firefox or use an HTTP/HTTPS link instead.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JUra5HnsbR_xmtQctkb2iVxRPuhPWhMB5M_zpbuGxTY/edit#

Comment: At this point, is it still possible download ftp from Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all browsers have pulled ftp support.

Currently, winSCP offers an option but it is not straightforward.

https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Finally, I managed to make it work using this option:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url

> Windows 10: The Settings app opens with Default Apps page. At the
> bottom of the page, click Set defaults by app link. Locate WinSCP in
> the programs list. After selecting WinSCP, click the Manage button.
> The File type and protocol associations page for WinSCP opens